# Why are the MeMenu and the messaging applet two separate things?

Tags: indicator, memenu, messaging-menu

When I look at them, their functionality seems to overlap so much that they could almost be merged:

- The MA is used to open Gwibber, but the MM is used to set the accounts and broadcast messages.
- The MA is used to open Empathy, but the MM is used to set the accounts and set a status (available, busy...).

All these could well be in different sections, either in the MA or the MM:

- Chat (set status, accounts).
- Mail (send mail, contacts).
- Broadcast (send message, accounts).
- Ubuntu One.
- About me.

So, why the decision to split them in two different indicators, thus taking extra space in the panel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered by MPT in the [Ayatana mailing list](https://lists.launchpad.net/ayatana/msg04065.html):

> Only because no-one has done the design work necessary to work out how
>   to merge them.

So, hopefully, they can be merged at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I think the merged one is available

run this:

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-applet-complete
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; my question does not address a particular need but just an interest about why a certain default is the way it is, though.

Comment: @Behzadsh Installing `indicator-applet-complete` won't get you a "merged" version - it's just a metapackage.

Comment: @fluteflute I remember in ubuntu 10.04, installing it add a "complete menu applet" to panel applets, since I remember it wasn't a metapackage. maybe I'm wrong!!